# Blocking a child/enclosing component of iterating components like p:dataTable using p:blockUI or pe:blockUI does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I'm targeting a `<p:dataTable>` to be blocked by `<pe:blockUI>` as follows.

```
<pe:blockUI target="dataTable" widgetVar="blockUIWidget">
    <h:outputText value="Sending data..."/>
</pe:blockUI>

<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="row" value="Test">
    <p:column>
        <p:commandLink id="link" value="Link" onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').block()" oncomplete="PF('blockUIWidget').unblock()"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Naturally, this functions well.

---

I need not target the entire data table but only the link inside the table. The following attempt to do so is unsuccessful.

```
<pe:blockUI target="dataTable:link" widgetVar="blockUIWidget">
    <h:outputText value="Sending data..."/>
</pe:blockUI>
```

Here, the value of the `target` attribute has been changed from `dataTable` to `dataTable:link` to make it refer to the link (the data table remains stationary).

In this case, it remains mute. Neither errors on the browser console nor any exceptions occur.

---

The same thing happens with `<p:blockUI>`. The following attempt functions well as it is meant for.

```
<p:blockUI block="dataTable" widgetVar="blockUI"/>

<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="row" value="Test">
    <p:column>
        <p:commandLink id="link" value="Link" onstart="PF('blockUI').show()" oncomplete="PF('blockUI').hide()"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Making `<p:blockUI>` point to the `<p:commandLink>` inside the table  as follows however, does not function.

```
<p:blockUI block="dataTable:link" widgetVar="blockUI"/>
```

Again no errors, no exceptions.

What is the point? Can enclosing components of iterating components not be targeted by `<p:blockUI>` or `<pe:blockUI>`?

Answer (score 0):

This works well, when a `<p/pe:blockUI>` is defined inside data table column/s themselves as follows.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="row" value="Test">
    <p:column>
        <!--Using PrimeFaces Extensions <pe:blockUI>-->
        <pe:blockUI target="link" widgetVar="blockUIWidget">
            <h:outputText value="Sending data..."/>
        </pe:blockUI>
        <p:commandLink id="link" value="Link" onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').block()" oncomplete="PF('blockUIWidget').unblock()"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <!--Using PrimeFaces <p:blockUI>-->
        <p:blockUI block="link1" widgetVar="blockLink1UI" />
        <p:commandLink id="link1" value="Link1" onstart="PF('blockLink1UI').show()" oncomplete="PF('blockLink1UI').hide()"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <!--Using PrimeFaces <p:blockUI>-->
        <p:blockUI block="link2" widgetVar="blockLink2UI" />
        <p:commandLink id="link2" value="Link2" onstart="PF('blockLink2UI').show()" oncomplete="PF('blockLink2UI').hide()"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```